# First time install: Ubuntu is incredibly slow.

Tags: graphics, performance

I just installed Ubuntu, and I must admit, I have no idea what I'm doing in linux. I installed it on my old Lenovo T60, and I was surprised at how slow it runs. It's a lot slower than my 2 year old WinXP install. Any tips? Just to illustrate how fresh I am, I don't even know how to get root in the terminal.

Comment: Can you share some key specifications of your lenovo, including graphics card type?

Answer (score 1):

Trying logging out, then click the gear on the login box to change to an "Ubuntu 2D" session.  This requires less in terms of video and CPU resources (it tends to work better on many older or slower machines).